# Ordenar los resultados de una consulta de acuerdo a los resultados de otra

Tags: php, mysql

Sucede que tengo dos tablas, **articles** y **likes**. En la primera, guardo una serie de artículos, y en la segunda, guardo la reacción de los usuarios a estos artículos.

Quiero ordenar los artículos (tabla article) en orden de mayor a menor reacción (tabla likes). Donde el único valor igual que compartirán ambas sería un ID.

Me explico:

Tabla Article:

- ID: 01 | Content: Aloja
- ID: 02 | Content: Aloja nuevamente
- ID: 03 | Content: Aloja otra vez mas

Tabla Likes:

- ID: 01 | Likes: 20
- ID: 02 | Likes: 70
- ID: 01 | Likes: 10

Quisiera saber como hacer esta consulta. Perdon si no me supe explicar bien heheh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saludos, 
Mas abajo te dejo la consulta que necesitas.

```
    Select A.ID, A.Content, B.Likes from Article A, Likes B where A.ID = B.ID 
group by A.ID, A.Content, B.Likes
order by B.Likes desc
```